# Changing the Settings item description text color in Android?

Tags: android, xml, text, colors, themes

I use a Samsung Vibrant, and one of the annoying bits that Samsung tossed on their TouchWiz skin was changing the color of the Settings menu item description text from white (AOSP) to light blue.

This looks okay as long as the skin is bluey-themed, but most ROMs seem to be leaning toward Gingerbread clones... doesn't look good with the green.

How can I change that settings description font color back to white, or even the orange it is in actual Android 2.3? Which xml file is the color property located in?

It seems to also spread to all apps you install, too... the blue text.

Comment: Samsung are annoying and override styles directly on certain tags in the XML layout. I've checked the Settings summary one before, it's a Samsung-specific thing and there's not really any nice way around it.

Answer (score 0):

For your app you will need to add a new style like this:

```
<resources>
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:textColor">#0198E1</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

And in your manifest file, in your preference activity add this line to apply your style:

```
android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
```

You could also check the default styles here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml

If you are referring to do it system wide, then you will probably need to find this styles.xml file and also need to have root.